# C# library logging

Tags: c#, logging, dll, trace

I have implemented my own C# logger class using `StreamWriter`. In my application, I have public static instance of this logger and I'm able to log anything from any part of application code, like:

```
Program.logger.Write(LogLevel.Info, "Log test");
```

I have also some C# dll library which I'm using in application.
The question is, am I able to add logging into library functions and link it somehow with application logger? I know about `Trace` class, but I don't know how to link it. I suppose that I have to trace in library functions, and then listen these traces in application code, but how?

I don't want to use any third-party libraries for logging.

Comment: Did you try to pass to some kind of initialization method of your library the instance of Program.logger?

Comment: The library contains more classes. I would have to pass logger instance into all of them. It would work, but I'm looking for some more elegant and efficient.

Comment: You could move the logger class inside the library and expose the instance as your Program class is doing now (probably through a static variable) Of course you should provide to the main program a method that initializes your log class. In this pattern the library classes knows the existence of the static instance of the logger

Comment: Thank you Steve. I didn't think about it from the opposite side like you (static Logger instance initialized inside the library, not in the main program).

Comment: Well, a logger seems to be a service needed by every program, so the logical place should be inside a library to be reused also by other programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can solve your problem. Here I describe how you can solve it through using the Trace class since this is the option you mentioned in your question. Please note that this might not be the best approach.

First create a custom [TraceListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class MyTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        //Here consume your static logger
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        //Here consume your static logger
    }
}
```

Then, at the entry point of your application, register the listener like this:

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new MyTraceListener());
```

Now if any code (even the ones in the library) use `Trace.WriteLine` like this:

```
Trace.WriteLine("From library");
```

You would be able to listen to that and forward it to your custom logger.

Comment: Thanks! This does make sense. I'll try to implement it this way.